# Is there MD5 support in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, hash, md5

For example, is there something like this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ <<do md5 on $1>>.mp3
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I highly doubt that. You should use PHP redirection. What is the problem to use `$_GET["foo"] = md5($_GET["foo"]);` in target php script (foo.php)?

Comment: @TomášZato Well, what I really wanted was to hash and straight-away access an mp3 file, if that is possible.

Comment: You can do this in PHP and then `readfile()` the MP3. Don't use languages and enviroments for different things than they are intended to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I found out this is not possible, but there can be modules loaded in Apache - once you create such module, that can introduce MD5 in existing `mod_rewrite` you can do this.
But I must warn you that you are going to slow down your server. Use PHP instead.

```
if(isset($_GET["file"])) {
   readfile(md5($_GET["file"]).".mp3");  //Outputs the file. Do not use echo file_get_contents.
}
```